# Does the Linux kernel load Nvidia GPU drivers (only) when needed?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lubuntu, gpu-driver, additional-drivers

I have built a portable Lubuntu installation on USB. In my pursuit of working on all x86_64 systems, I have successfully got it to work in both BIOS and UEFI environments, and also added Mac-specific Wi-Fi drivers and got them to work. Other than that, I have installed KDE Plasma. No other major changes. I want to clear the roadblock of GPUs.

So what I'm specifically looking to know is that if I install Nvidia drivers, this means that the kernel will auto-load these when booting from a system using an Nvidia GPU, correct ? This will still mean that I can boot from an Intel HD or AMD system flawlessly, and just as from a clean Linux install, correct?

Comment: This isn't a Linux support site, and I see nothing on-topic mentioned for this site - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @guiverc my apologies. I will move my question. However, if you do have an answer, please tell me.

Comment: @AnAnt If this relates to Ubuntu--like if what you're doing is [making a custom Ubuntu-based system](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6098/22949)--then please **[edit]** this question with details about that. (This would not just be to establish that it's related to Ubuntu, but also to give more information about what customizations you've made, which may help get good answers.) Otherwise, you may want to ask on [unix.se]; if you do, I still recommend saying more about the system you're making. Ordinarily, Intel and AMD graphics would still work, but that doesn't take any specifics into account.

Comment: @EliahKagan I did so. I'm making a Lubuntu (thereby Ubuntu-based) system.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you did not also remove any other drivers, installing an Nvidia driver should not break your customized Lubuntu system.

Possible ways to remove other drivers including uninstalling packages that provide them and recompiling your kernel without some modules. So if you're using a custom kernel, the real answer may depend on how you've customized it. Besides that, the drivers you started with--video and otherwise--should still be present.

If this is a customized live environment, then it's made to boot successfully and be usable on as wide a range of hardware as possible. If this customized system instead is based off an installed system, it should still work; after all, replacing your video card doesn't usually prevent Ubuntu from booting.

In much the same way that adding Wi-Fi drivers needed for some but not all machines didn't break wireless networking it for the other machines, adding video drivers that only some machines can use shouldn't break anything either.

I keep saying "should." That's because you'll still have to test it to ensure everything works properly. The drivers that were present before you added another one are still present, but it's possible your customizations have accidentally removed something, or even that there is a bug lurking in one or more Ubuntu packages that never affected this system until it was triggered by something you changed.

Comment: I will take a dive now and install Nvidia drivers. I do not have a custom kernel, the only thing changed is Mac wifi drivers and the desktop environment, which shouldn't impede the regular stuff.

Comment: I used sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440 and have the following screenshot - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YHiLE9L_2257nTqzgZBSXibWiM_9PSlQ/view?usp=sharing  .... Appears successful to me, am about to reboot on machine without Nvidia card, only IntelHD

Comment: Worked, thanks. Is this possible on Windows- to install Nvidia drivers , not removing IntelHD drivers , then simple slotting in the Nvidia GPU when mine is delivered ? I understand this may not be the best place to ask, after-all, we are linux people, but then still...

Comment: @AnAnt I don't know how well it would work to install Nvidia drivers in Windows before you have the card. But you can definitely have both drivers installed on Windows. Installing Nvidia drivers won't remove the Intel graphics drivers. You can even use both graphics adapters at the same time--on some systems even with the same display. I have a laptop with Windows on it. It has both an integrated Intel HD Graphics 630 and a discrete Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060. Usually the HD 630 is used, to save power. The GTX 1060 is automatically used for gaming (and for scientific computing like Folding@home).